# Multiple WordPress sites on one hosting

Tags: multisite, seo

I want to start building multiple `WordPress` blog sites(different niche), on one cloud hosting.

Every blog will have his own unique domain, but all of them will be on the same hosting.

Is this platform can affect the websites SEO ranking on `Google`?

What are the alternatives if I don't want to have a specific host for each website?

Comment: SEO questions aren't development questions, so are off-topic here, but why would this impact SEO? It wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have each site with a separate database (individual copies of WP), or one database with multiple sites (WP Multisite).

If you go Multisite, each sub-site can have its own domain assigned to it. Multisite has common themeing and plugins, although you can have a different theme for each sub-site.

Comment: this can impact on the seo of the website in google?

Comment: If the subsites are separate domains (URLs as in www.example.com ), then they are separate sites, and SEO will see them as separate sites. If they are set up as something like www.example.com/subsite1 then their SEO will be with www.example.com . If the main site is www.example.com, and a subsite is www.anotherdomain.com , then that is two separate domains for SEO purposes.